# Change Current Locale for Testing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, datetime

I need to change my Chrome browser's running javascript locale from English US to English UK in order to test functionality that relies on javascript's Date object. Is this based off of the browser settings? Or maybe my OS settings? I'm running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way and the best way to change your chrome browser locale settings is:

1. Just go to your desktop Google chrome shortcut, right click and properties. 
   You will notice your target with: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`
2. Change the target to:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --lang=en_US --user-data-dir=C:\ChromeUserDirs\EN_US
   ```

   etc. according to your locale that you would wanted to change.

As you can see I have changed my locale settings (default was English because I am living in UK)  to  US.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome now supports [emulating locales and locations](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-83/#locales) in Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just in case someone is still looking for it, what worked for me is changing the time zone of the OS. I tried this on Windows 10.